# How to perform Visibility Analysis using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, viewshed, visibility

How can I calculate Visibility using QGIS?

I have not found any suitable plugins for QGIS to do this.

Comment: Your question has been flagged up as of low quality due to its length.  I hope you may be open to reading this Meta Question about [**What makes a Good Question?**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question)

Comment: There is a saga gis visibility module. You could run that through processing if you have qgis 2.0.1

Comment: If we're guessing about the question as duplicate, then it isn't clear enough. Please put some effort into describing the problem (not just naming it)